# I want to override some CSS that says border:none to have border bottom. How can I do this?

Tags: css

I am working on an ionic project, and I have a material design css file that I am using because it adds some nice things that I am using.  However, here is one thing that is driving me nuts:

```
.list .item {
  border: none;
}
```

I am using lists a lot and in most places I do not want borders anyway.  However, in my menu, I do want borders.  How can I over ride this so it looks like this?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbQNZ

I only want borders to show in my menu and nowhere else.  If I make any changes, it shows borders everywhere.

Comment: Need to see some more specific CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as:

```
.list .item {
    border: none;
}

.list.with-border .item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="list with-border">
    <li class="item">first</li>
    <li class="item">second</li>
    <li class="item">third</li>
</ul>
```